# Unable to load dynamic library 'php_oci8_19.dll'

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Hy! I'm trying to use oci on windows, I found some linked issues, but I don't have any xampp, or apache, or anything, I'm only using the php built-in server. I enabled the oci extension in the php.ini file, but it does not work. I was looking for answer. I don't need any oracle database, there is a database, I only want to connect it with my app. I have the error above every time, when I'm trying to run any php command. So it does not work. The missing dll file is there, so I don't understand, why is it missing. I installed pear, and pecl, but pecl installations need openssl, openssl needs visualC++ and some other things... is there any other solution? Even though why does it not find that dll, if it's there... I downloaded Oracle Instant client and Oracle SDK, I unzipped it, set the environmental variables, but nothing changed... Please, help!

Comment: check the paths in the php.ini for the ext directory and for the entry that assigns the extension directory and the path to the dll must be as in the php.ini.

Comment: The extension dir is C:\php\ext and this is added to the path environment variable, and it's also declared in the php.ini file.
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext" 
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_oci8_19.dll' (tried: C:\php\ext\php_oci8_19.dll
But this file is exactly right there.

Comment: @Maestro Did you try out the steps in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to download the correct [`oci8_19.dll`](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8) if not already there and placed it under `your_xampp_directory\php\ext` folder.
- Enable/add this extension in your php.ini file.
- Add environment variable path for PHP.
- Then, you also need Oracle Instant client to load/run this properly. Download it from [`here`](https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html). Be mindful about `x86` or `x64` architecture of your windows machine and download the one that matches your machine specs.
- Add this Oracle instant client path too in your environment variable.
- Restart command prompt and type `php -v`. Voila! It runs smoothly and shows you *just* the PHP version, which means your oci extension loaded properly.

Comment: I wrote, I don't have xampp...

Comment: @Maestro Then it should just be your ext folder wherever your PHP resides!

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I did all the steps, you wrote me, moreover I downloaded also the oracle instant client SDK, now it threws another error... it's written in my language, but I turned it to english: The entry point of the procedure (zend_parse_arg_str_slow@@) is not found in the DLL (C:\php\ext\php_oci8_19.dll). And the command line still threws the original error: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_oci8_19.dll' (tried: C:\php\ext\php_oci8_19.dll However I have the up to date php version and I downloaded the up to date dll file...

Comment: @Maestro Did you do any renaming on the `php_oci8_19.dll` file?

Comment: No. I downloaded the DLL from the location, you linked me, it was a zip file, I extracted it, and there was a file with exactly that name, I copied it to the ext directory with overriding the original file.

Comment: @Maestro Is your dll and instant client compatible with your OS architecture? Like with 32 or 64 bit. Because these steps work just fine at my end.

Comment: The Instant Client is surely compatible, but the dll... I don't know, it's not marked as any compatibility...
By the way, now it shows the error message: the given procedure is not found. So when I type "php" into command line, and press enter, there's an error popup with the The entry point of the procedure (zend_parse_arg_str_slow@@) is not found in the DLL (C:\php\ext\php_oci8_19.dll) text, and the command line writes, PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_oci8_19.dll' (tried: C:\php\ext\php_oci8_19.dll (The given procidure is not found...

Comment: @Maestro What is your php version?

Comment: My php version is 8.0.12

Comment: @Maestro Can you add your current steps and screenshots to your question?

Comment: Okay, I got it... during making screenshots for pesent my steps I realized, that the dll, which I downloaded is for PHP 8.1... I thought, I have the up-to-date php version, but I have the 8.0.12, as I told it... sorry! I downloaded the older version of the dll and magic hapened. It works. Thank you very much for help!!! I'm really thankful!

Comment: @Maestro Glad it worked. _if only_ any of my steps in my answers helped, could you tick the answer so that others who have the same issue and land on this page know that it is a working solution?

Comment: I tried, but I'm new here yet, so can't vote.

Comment: @Maestro Fair enough but I actually meant this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379675/who-marks-green-tick-in-stack-overflow

Comment: Ahh, okay, got it! And you got it!